# I am having trouble visualizing sorting algorithms

Tags: reactjs, sorting, settimeout, dom-manipulation, array-algorithms

I am trying to visualize a sorting algorithm with react, my algorithm works fine but i want to link it to divs on the DOM that change their height as the sorting algorithms sorts a given array, i have only made it work at the last stage, for example divs on the DOM take their height from an unsorted array and when i click on the sort button, instead of dynamicly changing their height as the algorithm sorts the unsorted array, they just wait untill the algorithm finishes sorting and then in one instance the div go from unsorted height to sorted height (i have tried to do setTimeout but it never worked for me as it intended, it just does one timeout instead of doing it in every iteration).
This is my code:

```
function App() {
  const [array, setArray] = useState();
  const elements = useRef();
  const test = (Array) => { 
      if(Array){
        for(let i=0; i < Array.length; i++){
          elements.current.children[i].style.height = `${Array[i]*2}vh`;
        }
      } 
  };
  useEffect(()=> {
    const startArray = [];
    for(let i=0; i < 51; i++){
      let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 27);
      if(randomNumber !== 0){
        startArray.push(randomNumber)
      }
    }
    setArray(startArray)
  }, [])
  const bubbleSort = arraY => {
    let iteration = true;
    let shouldContinue = false;
    let count = arraY.length-1;
    while(iteration){
        shouldContinue = false
        if(count > 0){
            for(let i=0; i < count; i++){
              shouldContinue = true;
                if(arraY[i] > arraY[i+1]){
                  let smaller = arraY[i+1];
                  arraY[i+1] = arraY[i];
                  arraY[i] = smaller;
                  test(arraY);
                  }
                }
        }
            count = count -1

            if(!shouldContinue){
                iteration = false
            }
    }
    return array
  }
  const sort = ()=> {
    bubbleSort(array);
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <nav>
        <h1 onClick={sort}>BUBBLE SORT</h1>
        <h1 onClick={sort}>--- SORT</h1>
        <h1 onClick={sort}>--- SORT</h1>
        <h1 onClick={sort}>--- SORT</h1>
      </nav>
      <div className='container' ref={elements}>
        {array && array.map(item=>{
          return <div style={{height: `${item*2}vh`}}></div>
        })
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to do one sort operation, and then set the state, so that react re-renders. You also will need to set some timeout, to avoid it all happening so quickly you can't see anything. Something like this:

```
const [currentlyAt, setCurrentlyAt] = useState(0);

const bubbleSort () => {

   const newArray = [...]
   // perform one step of bubble sort, storing my position in the sort
   // with setCurrentlyAt, so I can resume it next time I'm called
   
   setArray(newArray);
   setTimeout(() => bubbleSort(), 500);  
}
```

This allows one step (a single item swap in bubble array) to be performed, state updates so it'll rerender, and timeout gives time for the rerender to be seen by the user before resuming the bubble sort and doing the next swap.

Also, please, don't use `arraY` and `Array` as variable names to avoid shadowing `array`, use something like `partiallySorted` or at least `arr`. And you don't need to `useRef` at all, your logic where you map over array and have div heights based on array value works fine, you don't want to manually edit the style using a ref.

Comment: i have tried to use setArray to change the array to the newly semi sorted array, my react app is not rerendering. divs still have the old values although when i console.log the array it changed.

Comment: Also i am using the useRef because the app is not rerendering itself so i am trying to manually rerender it.